# Symfony service is already initialized, you cannot replace it

Tags: symfony

I have a test where I want to mock `RouterInterface` like this

```
    public function testRoutNotFoudn(): void
    {
        $client = self::createClient();
        $container = $client->getContainer();
        assert($container instanceof ContainerInterface);

        $container->set(
            'test.' . RouterInterface::class,
            Mockery::mock(
                RouterInterface::class,
                static function (MockInterface $mock): void {
                    $mock->shouldReceive('getRouteCollection')->andReturn(new RouteCollection());
                },
            )->makePartial(),
        );

       // trigger endpoint and assertions, it's not important here
```

to make it work I have `config/packages/test/service.yaml`

```
services:
  test.Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface:
    alias: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
    public: true
```

all works correctly at this point, I am able to mock `RouterInterface` and set it to the container.

Next I want to introduce a custom monolog processor, to extend log data and that processor needs to inject `RouterInterface`, for example like this:

```
final class RequestDataProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function __construct(private readonly RouterInterface $router)
    {

    }

    public function __invoke(array $record): array
    {
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            return $record;
        }

        $record['route] = $htis-router->match('some_route');


        return $record + $context;
    }
}
```

and registered in `services.yaml`:

```
    App\Logger\RequestDataProcessor:
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor, handler: main }
```

After I added `RequestDataProcessor` the test started to fail because this processor initialized somewhere during client creation, and at a moment of setting the mocked object I'm getting the error `The "test.Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface" service is already initialized, you cannot replace it.`

Is it possible somehow to fix this??

Comment: I do not know why you define `test.Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface` an Service? What are you trying to do? But 'test.Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface' then exists in the dependency container so you can not add it.

Comment: as I mentioned if I remove `RequestDataProcessor ` I can do it, and in general what to do if I want to mock something?

Comment: and `test.Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface` is just to make the service public, you can override service in `config/packages/test/service.yaml` to make it public, and adding `test.` prefix is just a convention as far as I know.

Comment: but the issue is that I want to mock `RouterInterface ` or any other class, but looks like it's not always possible as somewhere down the road that class can be already initialized